# Showing error message in html form using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

My html:

```
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="login.php" onsubmit="return(validate());" >
    <p><label><b>Username</b></label>
        <input name = "Username" type = "text" maxlength = "30">
    </p>

    <p><label><b>Password</b></label>
        <input name = "Password" type = "text" maxlength = "30">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Login">
        <input type = "reset" value = "Clear">
        <span class="errorMsg" id="validation"></span>
    </p>
</form>
```

My php code:

```
echo " <script type= \'text/javascript\'> 
           document.getElementById('validation').innerHTML = 'Username or Password is Incorrect';
       </script>";
```

What I want to achieve is showing that error message near the submit buttons.

html and php codes are located in 2 different files.
index.html and login.php both are in the same folder.

Comment: Including your php file in the html will solve this problem: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$msg="";
// put user name and password validation here
// if login fails set $msg value
// set $msg value
?>
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validate();" >
            <p><label><b>Username</b></label>
                <input name = "Username" type = "text" maxlength = "30">
            </p>

                <p><label><b>Password</b></label>
                    <input name = "Password" type = "text" maxlength = "30">
                </p>
                <p>
                <input type = "submit" value = "Login">
                <input type = "reset" value = "Clear">
                <?php if($msg!="") { ?>
                <span class="errorMsg" id="validation">Username or Password is Incorrect</span>
                <?php } ?>
            </p>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your index file extension: from `index.html` to `index.php` to be able to parse php code.

Then at the top of your index file place file inclusion:

```
<?php include('login.php');?>
```

BTW, you don't need to do it with javascript, you can as well echo this message directly in your "validation" span like this:

```
<span class="errorMsg" id="validation"><?php echo $message;?></span>
```

and then in login.php, which you include at the top of file, you assign this text to $message variable:

`$message = 'Username or Password is Incorrect';`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it without javascript as well:

Login-Form:

```
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="login.php" onsubmit="return(validate());" >
        <p><label><b>Username</b></label>
            <input name = "Username" type = "text" maxlength = "30">
        </p>

            <p><label><b>Password</b></label>
                <input name = "Password" type = "text" maxlength = "30">
            </p>
            <p>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Login">
            <input type = "reset" value = "Clear">
            <?php if (isset($_GET['errorcode']) && $_GET['errorcode'] == "loginFailed") : ?>
                <span class="errorMsg" id="validation">Username or Password is Incorrect</span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>
    </form>
```

And the login.php:

```
    if(!validateUserPassword()){
       header("Location: index.php?errorcode=loginFailed");
    }

    //TODO: if valide show loginpage.

    function validateUserPassword(){
        if(isset($_POST['Username']) && isset($_POST['Password'])){
            //TODO: validate username & password and return true if valide
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to require JavaScript and have no action fall-back, just have the validate() function handle the response itself. E.g, Just evaluate the response from PHP.

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
  function validate() {
    // perform ajax request via your preference
    //...get response
    document.getElementById('validation').innerHTML = 'message based on response...';
    return false
  } </script>
```

```html
<form ... onsubmit="validate();">
```